# Profiling JAX code: What is redzone_checker and why does it take so much time?

Tags: gpu, profiling, tensorboard, jax, google-jax

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825444/what-is-redzone-checker-profiling-my-tensorflow-application-on-a-gpu) but am still unclear on what the `redzone_checker` kernel is doing and why. Specifically, should it be taking > 90% of my application's runtime? TensorBoard reports that it is taking the vast majority of the runtime of my JAX code, and I'd like to know

1. Is it actually the case that this kernel is taking way too much time, or is this a side effect of profiling JAX with TensorBoard (i.e., the output is misleading in some way)?
2. Is there a way to reduce the amount of time taken by the `redzone_checker` kernel? Is that even a good idea?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

make sure warmup before profiling.

it maybe jit compiling time.